# Error Bootstrap-toggle

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Bueno no me quueria  aparecer los switch generados por http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

solo me salia el checkbox...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Index.html lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

*clea

  
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
    
  
  
    
      You are using an outdated</strong> browser. Please [upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>](http://browsehappy.com/)*

```
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="container">
<div ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
 <script>
   !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
   (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
   r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
   }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-toggle/doc/script.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-store/angular-local-store.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngSweetAlert/SweetAlert.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap2-toggle.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/login.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/service/all.services.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Bien tenia todo correcto el problema es que no era compatible con angulajs, por eso es necesario instalar otra liberia :

http://ziscloud.github.io/angular-bootstrap-toggle/

Comment: Algun error del log del navegador? Haz inspeccionado elemento?

Comment: ninguno @sioesi

Comment: @sioesi lo solucione... era angularjs...

Comment: excelente!, deja la respuesta por si alguien la necesitase en algun momento!

Comment: @sioesi sabes utilizar ng-change ? tengo una duda :o

Comment: Si Hernan, consulta nomas :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47476/discussion-between-sioesi-and-hernan-humana).

Comment: podemos pasar a un chat?  :o

Comment: Si, ya te deje invitado a 1